# openssl passwd password only works briefly

Tags: ubuntu, password, openssl, useradd

I am having a strange issue setting up linux VM instances.  Please forgive me if this is basic, I am not a linux systems programmer (usually).  I am trying to script the launching of 20+ linux instances at once to be used by a CI/CD pipeline (Jenkins).  I have a script that runs when the linux instance boot up, which begins with this:

```
sudo useradd -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 <SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_HERE>) myNewUser
```

I had used this script some months ago with success. On booting these up, I could ssh into them with username `myNewUser` and password `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_HERE`.  I set up a credential in Jenkins to use this, and it worked great.

I need to do this again.  I ran this script to boot up more instances, and I was able to ssh into them with that username/password....for a short time.  I noticed that after a day, or maybe it was even just an hour or two, the password stopped working.  When trying again at a later time, the password was invalid?

Why is this?  Am I setting this up wrong?  How can I programatically set a username and password to be used a service account, that does not expire right away?  I am working with a company version of Ubuntu-16.  Please let me know if there are other details you'd need to help debug this.

Comment: Your `useradd` command does not include anything to specify expiration times, so either you have expiration set by default, or something later in the script that explicitly sets password expiration for this account, or the passwords are becoming invalid for some other reason. The general support for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ended in April 2021, so unless your company is doing its own security support, the "company version of Ubuntu-16" might have known vulnerabilities by now, and passwords becoming invalid just might be a sign of the systems getting hacked and/or infested with malware.

Comment: I realized the `-1` there should be a `--maxdays -1`, or `--maxdays 99999` - I'm not sure how that *ever* worked.  AFAIK there's nothing in my script that overwrites that.  Shouldn't that set the expiration to (functionally) forever?

Comment: The `-1` is an option for `openssl passwd`, specifying the MD5 based password algorithm, identifiable by the `$1$` prefix on the password hashes. That's an old and weak type of hash. You should be using `-6` (SHA512) or `-5` (SHA256) instead if your "company version of Ubuntu-16" supports them. But that has nothing to do with password expiration.

Comment: Unless you have specified password expiration by default (by using `useradd -D`), or `PASS_MAX_DAYS` has been set in `/etc/login.defs` (perhaps by built-in defaults in your "company version of Ubuntu-16"), your command should result in an account that does not expire. If you want, you could change the command to `sudo useradd -K PASS_MAX_DAYS=-1 -m -p ...` to explicitly turn off password aging for the account. But if the system is internet-accessible and the service account password is not a strong one, you might be getting hacked by automated malware.